# What happen if I try to run OpenGL 4.4 code on an unsupported graphic card?

Tags: opengl

I'm learning OpenGL because I'd like to build my own engine.
I'd like to know what happens if I try to run OpenGL 4.4 code (the latest version at the moment of writing) on an unsupported graphic card ? (I mean for example a graphic card that support up to 4.1 OpenGL). Does it fails even to start ? or, it start but fails to render ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The application will throw an exception when unsupported features are encountered, I guess. You should always check for support and output a reasonable error message in such a case.

Comment: But would be possible to add new OpenGL compatibility to a graphic card that doesn't support it natively ? or it is just an hardware aspect that can't be upgraded by just drivers ?

Comment: Drivers sometimes do get updated to support newer features of APIs. I am not really sure about OGL. Wait for an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C and C++, you just wouldn't get the functions to run it. You'd send the request for a 4.4 context and get a NULL context back (indicating that it wasn't created.) You'd make a `wglGetProcAddress` call and get NULL back for the function that you requested an address to.

If the hardware doesn't support it then your stuck without. There might be a chance that the user could upgrade their graphics drivers, but if the card is to old then the company will just stop updating them. They have no reason to worry about a 5 year old graphics card, when they have 10 to worry about just in the last 2 years. Then there's no guarantee that the graphics card would be able to handle such things. A major thing that changed in OpenGL is they moved to a shader-programmable pipeline. I'm sure that had quite an effect on how the hardware needed to be made. And with new APIs and features coming out, there where a lot of things back then that I doubt they would've been prepared for in the hardware design, so it's quite likely that some graphics cards are just stuck with insufficient support.

If you implemented OpenGL in software, you could use all functions that you implemented. But hardware acceleration would be difficult. You might be able to speed it up using things like OpenCL, and CUDA. Though, those are newer technologies as-well.

If you want hardware support, I would be to create an abstraction layer for your application to use. Create a basic interface class, with pure virtual functions, that has calls to all the function that you need (I'll call it `GraphicsAPI`). Give it the basic functions you need, like `AttachToWindow`, `RenderObject`, `CompileShader`, `UseShader`, `CreateTexture`, etc. Then create a class called `OGL44` that inherits `GraphicsAPI`, and implements all of those functions using the OpenGL 4.4 API. You could then create a class that inherits `GraphicsAPI` and implements functions according to the OpenGL 3.0 API, and use them interchangeably by passing them as a `GraphicsAPI` class to where it's needed. You could also look into how other APIs, like [Ogre3D](http://www.ogre3d.org/), handle it. They have the same problem to work-around.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! So If I've understood correctly, is possible to use new OpenGL functions on unsupported graphic cards (in software), but then the result will be slow due to the lack of hardware acceleration, is this right ? What I still don't understand very well is: how is possible for a driver upgrade to make a card to support new opengl if their hardware can't ? Thanks.

Comment: Correct. It would be slow. The Mesa 3D Graphics library, actually, is a software implementation of OpenGL, You could get an idea of just how much slower software rendering is with that. As for drivers supporting new OpenGL versions, it depends on what was was added between the two versions. I'm not sure of how companies make their graphics cards, so I cant say for sure.

Comment: As an example, the deprecation OpenGL recently had of the immediate mode. Immediate mode was something that the GPU could be optimized for. And, if you graphics card is old enough, Shaders where not yet introduced. So graphics cards only had to react to a small set of commands (`glBegin`, etc.) They didn't have to worry about running shader code or having to work with GB of data stored as massive buffers within 3D textures and so forth. So they where optimized for running the small commands. And and no idea as to how to run shader code, because shaders didn't exist.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking about that maybe new drivers can add new OpenGL support even on not compatible hardware, because they use software implementations of what the hardware is not able to do.

Comment: They could, but that would defeat the purpose of the driver. The driver drives the graphics card, with minimal CPU overhead to do so. The purpose of having the driver and the graphics card in the first place is to have **hardware acceleration** for the API. Otherwise they would just be providing a library, which could be done with Mesa and friends.

Comment: Good answer but: "they moved to a shader-programmable pipeline. I'm sure that had quite an effect on how the hardware needed to be made" - it's actually the other way around.  Hardware had been emulating FFP via shaders *long* before OpenGL made this transition.  So OpenGL had *no* effect on hardware; hardware is what had an effect on OpenGL.